# Import module symbols via parent directory

Tags: python

I have a Python directory called `work` with a number of modules containing classes relevant to that module. For example, `student` contains `Grades, Classes, Attendance`. My goal is that instead of:

```
from work.student import Grades
```

I would like to simply invoke:

```
from work import Grades
```

i.e., I would like to pull all of the inner symbols into the parent module. I realize that I could put a file named __init__.py in there and manually import everything. i.e. `from .student import *` etc.

I want to know if there's an easier and automatic way of doing this.

Comment: `from .student import *`

Answer (score 0):

From your question I am getting a project picture like below:

```
work/
├── __init__.py
└── student.py
```

In student.py, you have classes --> Grades, Classes, Attendance

As **Krishna** mentioned above, you can do the following in the **init**.py under work directory (or module in python terms).

```
__init__.py

**"""
Place any module level settings, env variables, module level declarations, etc  
"""**
from student import Grades, Classes, Attendace
```

Now you can import the classes in students modules as:

```
from work import Grades
from work import Classes
from work import Attendance
```